# Bootstrap navbar not expanding on mobile

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have an issue with bootstrap navbar. It's not expanding on mobile after click on hamburger icon. Do you have any idea how to fix it?
Below is my code and link to my page

http://blog.medytacja.net.pl/navbartest.html

I use bootstrap 4.3.1. I checked links and it work correctly. I have no idea what happened here.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Medytacja.net.l" />
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Nauka medytacji. Blog o medytacji - Mindfulness Budda</title>
<meta name="description" content="Blog o medytacji i rozwoju. Odpowiadamy na 
pytania, jak medytować? Blog o tematyce Mindfulness oraz Budzie. Medytować to 
sztuka ćwieczenia umysłu. Nauka medytacji. Naucz się z nami."/>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="CSS/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>


  </head>
   <body>
   <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" 
aria- 
   expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span 
class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call your jQuery before your bootstrap.min.js because Bootstrap is using jQuery attributes.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Medytacja.net.l" />
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Nauka medytacji. Blog o medytacji - Mindfulness Budda</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Blog o medytacji i rozwoju. Odpowiadamy na 
        pytania, jak medytować? Blog o tematyce Mindfulness oraz Budzie. Medytować to 
        sztuka ćwieczenia umysłu. Nauka medytacji. Naucz się z nami."/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script> <!-- look at here I changed the jquery position -->
        <script src="CSS/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
        <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button 
                    class="navbar-toggler" 
                    type="button" 
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" 
                    aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" 
                    aria-expanded="false" 
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                >
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```